# sync salesforce events (Custom object) to google calendar

Tags: salesforce, mule, google-calendar-api, mule-connector

The client has 1000 + Franchises, and on client corporate gmail account 1000 + Franchise calendars were created and each franchise calendar was shared (read only) to respective Franchise gmail account. When customers create meeting request on franchise website, events will be created in respective franchise calendars, and franchises get notified via email, gmail alerts etc.

Now client moved to Saleforce and each franchise was given access to experience cloud (franchise center details are in serviceterritory object), franchise website linked to salesforce and events are saved in salesforce custom object (attendee name, attendee contact details etc. in Attendee__c object) when customer creates a meeting request.

so how to create the events on franchise google calendar(s) whenever new / cancel meeting request comes to Attendee__c salesforce object?

Can we do this from Salesforce itself?

alternatively is there anyway to accomplish this using mulesoft?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do that with or without Mulesoft. If you want to do it using salesforce, you can do it using triggers / process builder (not an expert in SF so maybe there are more options). Otherwise mulesoft is definitely a possibility. You will need to finalize an approach, because the answer will depend a lot on that so this question can not be answered without an update.

Comment: Thank you Harshank. Planning to go with mulesoft approach as I found google calendar connector.

Comment: Okay, so it is still not clear what you are struggling with, Do you need help with the mulesoft's implementation, or do you need help to figure out a way to send the `Attendee__c` information from salesforce to mulesoft ?

Comment: I need help with Mulesoft implementation. 

I'm trying to implement events insert using Mulesoft google calendar connector, it says "OAuth authorization dance not yet performed for resourceOwnerId null". Any idea what it mean? looks like it is related to Resource Owner Id in Google connector, I got this error when I left it as blank and testing.

Comment: Yeah, I can help you with this. However, you will need to either update this question or close this and create a new one with the update details. Try to provide details on what you have tried so far and what error are you getting

Comment: Thank you Harshank, I posted a new Q and the url is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72340351/mulesoft-google-connector-to-create-an-event